# Control M does not get error from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, control-m

I have a very simple stored procedure. Here just an example that can reproduce the error. I want to schedule some procedures under Control-M and avoid a multitude of applications.

I added a simple THROW, in order to have an error. In the past similar errors where handled by applications. Here an example:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[test_my_error] AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @divide INT = 0

BEGIN TRY
    PRINT 'Let''s try procedure [test_my_error]'
    SELECT 100 / @divide
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    --This is just a test
    THROW;
END CATCH

END
```

If I run this in SQL Server Management Studio, I have an error and the following output:

> Let's try procedure [test_my_error]
>
> (0 rows affected) Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
> test_my_error, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 0] Divide by zero error
> encountered.

It is what I expected.

Then I build my job in Control-M and I have this log:

```
16:13:29 14/06/2021 SUBMITTED TO host01 5105 16:13:29
14/06/2021  STARTED AT 20210614161329 ON host01 5101 16:13:29
14/06/2021  JOB STATE CHANGED TO Executing  5120 16:13:30
14/06/2021  ENDED AT 20210614161330. OSCOMPSTAT 0. RUNCNT 7 5100
16:13:30 14/06/2021 ENDED OK. NUMBER OF FAILURES SET TO 0   5133
16:13:30 14/06/2021 JOB STATE CHANGED TO Analyzed   5120 16:13:30
14/06/2021  Job STATE CHANGED TO Post processed 5120
```

And in the output:

```
Statement Messages:
-------------------
Let's try procedure [test_my_error]

@RETURN_VALUE = ERROR
Exit Code    = 0
Exit Message = Normal completion
```

Versions are:

- SQL Server 2017
- Control-M for Databases 9.0.19.200

So error is ignored. How can I have the error intercepted?

Answer (score 1):

Two points;

1. Are you running this via Control-M for Databases? It is a module that runs under the Control-M Agent and gives you more control over DB jobs. It is definitely worth considering if you plan to run loads of stored procs and the like.
2. Windows is notoriously bad with exit codes (or Return Codes, to use the big boys term). You get an exit code = 0 in the cases where the tasks has cleared failed. The Control-M output is whatever would be in "standard out" (in Unix terms). Fortunately Control-M can catch text strings, which is handy when the exit code cannot be relied upon. Simply do this in the post-processing (i.e. last tab) -

Actions --> On/Do actions -->
on specific statement ouput
Statement *
Code * RETURN_VALUE = ERROR *
Do Set to NOTOK

See here for example -

https://community.bmc.com/s/article/How-to-use-On-specific-statement-output-in-a-Control-M-job-definition-s-On-Do-Actions